# hybris is not storing # in any value

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I have added # character in name, emailId and address. But when I see in hmc or backoffice , hash(#) is removed.  name and emailId exist without hash.
Why hybris is not taking # character in any attribute value?

Answer (score 2):

The de.hybris.platform.servicelayer.web.XSSFilter class strips the `#` character from the input fields. You can test it by adding the following value to your local.properties:

```
xss.filter.enabled=false
```

Once you do this, you will be able to capture data containing a `#` character. But since you don't want to disable XSSFilter, so the only way around it is to override the doFilter method on XSSFilter and add some logic to exclude data  that would contain `#` character.

Also, if you are trying to save such values at other places like local.properties, then please try storing the value like below, use `\\` before `#` symbol:

```
property.value=hybris\\#value
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me this answer. It is working fine. I also want to know the reason why hybris is not storing # (hash) in database bydefault.

Comment: Why do you say that XSSFilter remove the # char? Where have you seen that? XSSFilter use the pattern defined in keys `xss.filter...`, I don't see any `#` filter in the ootb config. Can you provide a reference that prove your statement? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @alain.janinm, I found a similar question on Hybris Experts and thought of providing the answer here. I personally did not verify the solution.
https://experts.hybris.com/questions/52907/password-field-not-allowing-special-character.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen this answer too but I can't really understand it. I'm curious to know what is behind this. Thanks for the reply anyway!